# How to resolve Laravel Foreign Key error?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I created 2 laravel migrations, the first one runs perfectly, the second gives me an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

I'm not sure what is wrong in my foreign key, can someone help me ?

Here is my first Schema:

```
    Schema::create('cryptocurrencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('symbol')->unique();
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->longtext('description');
    });
```

Here is my second Schema:

```
Schema::create('cryptocurrencies_quotes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('symbol');
    $table->string('slug');
    $table->integer('cryptocurrency_id');
    $table->bigInteger('circulating_supply');
    $table->bigInteger('total_supply');
    $table->double('price');
    $table->double('volume_24h');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::table('cryptocurrencies_quotes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('cryptocurrency_id')->references('id')->on('cryptocurrencies')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It mean that the value we pass to table2 has foreign doesn't exist in table1 as a parent
In your second table change

```
$table->integer('cryptocurrency_id');
```

for

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('cryptocurrency_id');
```